# Sense checking xpath formatting

Tags: xml, xpath

I am trying to use IBM's AlchemyAPI to select a portion of text on a website.
As a demo, I am trying to return the ingredients list from Jamie Oliver's website.

This ingredients list is found at

```
<ul class="ingred-list ">
    <li>Ingredient etc</li>
```

The api calls for an XPath expression to sort through the text, however my current curl call isn't working. I've been using this cheatsheet as a guide to XPath but I still can't get the formatting right.

Can anyone point out where this is going wrong?

```
curl 'https://gateway-a.watsonplatform.net/calls/url/URLGetText?url=http://www.jamieoliver.com/recipes/turkey-recipes/cooking-the-turkey&outputMode=json&apikey=165151eaa159554b143b70449059d4139efd9b1b&sourceText=xpath&xpath=//ul[@class="ingred-list"]/li’
```

XPath

`xpath=//ul[@class="ingred-list"]/li`

Comment: Well, I don't know the tool you use but requesting `outputMode=json` when you want to use XPath sounds odd, as XPath is for selecting nodes in XML or XHTML but not for selecting data from JSON (unless you live on the bleeding edge of XPath 3.1).

Comment: Output works with just calling `xpath=//li` but then I get everything on the web page. Are you able to offer any advice to the question: RE correct formatting to return the values of `<li>` with the parent of `<ul class="ingred-list ">`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given `<ul class="ingred-list ">`, I think you need the XPath `//ul[@class="ingred-list "]/li` also having that space. Or use `//ul[contains(@class,"ingred-list")]/li`.

Comment: Unfortunately that doesn't work. I am returned the following error:
`-bash: syntax error near unexpected token `('`

Comment: Add a tag for bash then so that someone can help with the command line. I think in terms of XPath my suggestion is fine, what's left is to find some way to escape the string on your command line.